# Deployed war in JBoss via cargo-maven2-plugin not accessible via JBoss AS Admin console

Tags: maven-2, jboss, jboss5.x, cargo, maven-cargo

I'm deploying a war to a remote JBoss 5.1.0 using the following POM config

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <container>
                <containerId>jboss51x</containerId>
                <type>remote</type>
            </container>
            <configuration>
                <type>runtime</type>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.hostname>localhost</cargo.hostname>
                    <cargo.remote.username>****</cargo.remote.username>
                    <cargo.remote.password>****</cargo.remote.password>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <deployer>
                <type>remote</type>
                <deployables>
                  <deployable>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <properties>
                        <context>/${project.artifactId}</context>
                    </properties>
                  </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </deployer>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deployer-deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deployer-undeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify-deploy</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deployer-deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution> 
                <execution>
                    <id>clean-undeploy</id>
                    <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deployer-undeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution> 
            </executions>
      </plugin>
```

It works fine and the web project is UP via http://localhost:8080/my-web-project/

But there's no trace of it in the JBoss AS admin console (http://localhost:8080/admin-console/)

Is it normal ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote deployment on JBoss AS with Cargo has been only partially supported during a long time, and this might explain the problem. This was logged in <strike>[CARGO-416](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-416)</strike> which has been fixed in Cargo 1.0.3.

So, as of Cargo 1.0.3, remote deployment on JBoss should be now fully supported and is documented in the dedicated [JBoss Remote Deployer](http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+Remote+Deployer) wiki page. Give it a try.